# restore data on couchbase CE 3.0.1 mac

Tags: macos, couchbase

I was trying to restore a couchbase backup from production server when this happens

```
Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Keys mosesliao$ /Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbrestore ~/2016-01-28T000001Z/2016-01-28T000001Z-full/ http://localhost:8091/ --bucket-source=Game
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/couchstore.py", line 26, in <module>
    _lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libcouchstore-1.dll, 6): image not found
```

Any idea how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are using OS X 10.11 El Capitan. If this is the case then that version of OS X is not supported for the 3.0.1 release since 3.0.1 was released before OS X 10.11. The reason for the issue you are seeing is because Apple added SIP in 10.11 and this caused some our our code to break. One option would be for you to restore your data from a different machine to your laptop. You will also need to add the --rehash argument as @Francois Cerbelle mentioned because the OS X version of Couchbase uses 64 vbuckets and the production versions use 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your production server are using Windows or Linux and you tried to restore on a Mac. Mac has a different number of vBuckets per bucket and you need the --rehash argument